# Fixed child of flexed div inheriting flex properties

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a child of a `flexed div`, of which all children I want to be 100% of the dom (other's off screen to be translated on later with transitions). I did this by giving the flexed parent width of `100%*numChildren` and giving each child `width 100%;`.

This works as expected except I have a modal popup with `position fixed` in one of these children. This position fixed is given `width` and `height` of `100%`; however, it seems to base those values of the several hundred percent `flex parent` and not the actual dom. `Absolute` does the same thing. Why does this happen? How do I fix it?

1) Should I be doing this differently? If I don't do this I have an issue that the `widths` of the children do not satisfy `100%.`

I want to override the following behavior:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/absolute-positioned-children

Comment: can you put together a live example?

Comment: @SergChernata I found a link describing this behavior by browsers. How to override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `width: 100%` you can use `width: 100vw`, which means the width of the viewport. Or use absolute positioning to the popup and relative positioning to the flex item.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
#container > div {
  width: 100vw;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1<span class="abs">Absolute</span></div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```